# Is there a way to have the title attribute of an html element to display for a longer time?

Tags: html, tooltip

Without using tooltip plugins or such, is there a way to extend the duration of time that the title attribute of an html element will display for?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The tooltip you see by default is a function of the browser and is not controllable from the page markup. Your only option is some form of javascript-based tooltip.

Comment: Not everyone has JavaScript. Not everyone can see, either. So perverting the title attribute for stylistic reasons needs to be carefully considered from a web accessibility standpoint.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that is what I was thinking.  Matt - our site requires that js is enabled, so I don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Chris never suggested removing the title attribute, and a javascript tooltip longener wouldn't stop non-javascript browsers from working in any way.

Comment: Grant, a good tooltip library would allow you to leave the title on the elements and remove them using javascript as the tooltips were dynamically added. This has the advantage of still displaying the native title tooltips if javascript is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to extend the time tooltips display on your own machine, or on a client machine?

If you are changing the amount of time you want tooldips to display, then you'll create your own tooltips with javascript or some fancy CSS.

I use a jquery function that handles tooltips. You set tooltips to disappear after a set amount of time.

There are a bunch of options available. [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltips)

In whatever the tooltip's end event, probably a `.mouseout(function(){` type of event you'd just change something that looks like

```
.mouseout(function(){
    //some code that gets rid of the tooltip, like my_tooltip.css({left:"-9999px"});
});
```

to

```
.mouseout(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     //some code that gets rid of the tooltip, like my_tooltip.css({left:"-9999px"});
   }), 1000); //<- one second
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, and it varies between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip you're on about here is something that's dependant on the browser. The browser (or the operating system) defines how long this tooltip shows for.

Unless you want to change the browser, and provide all visitors to your site with that browser version, then I'd suggest you use a javascript solution for tooltips.