# How to increase default hover duration of <a> title attribute (tooltip)

Tags: html, tooltip, hover

Is there a way to increase the duration of a tool tip displayed using the title attribute of an  html tag?

Currently in IE it appears to only have about a 5 second duration and then disappears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have the title attribute of an html element to display for a longer time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245936/is-there-a-way-to-have-the-title-attribute-of-an-html-element-to-display-for-a-l)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is operating system dependent and you should not try to override that.

The best way will be to create a custom tooltip.

Here are some good ones

[jQuery Tooltip Plugin Demo](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: +1 for being completely correct.  OP should look for a nice lightweight tooltip library, there are tons.

Comment: thanks!  I wasn't sure if it was OS controlled of if it could somehow be set with css.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate further on phoenix' answer. Custom tooltips will allow you great flexibility in their appearance and layout. You need to get a JavaScript library (for example, jquery, or mootools) and get a plugin to show them. Then you will link the JQuery .js file, the plugin's one, and the css, finally you will add some markup to make it work.

For example, this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ or this one: http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

They are usually quite simple to install, the only requirement is that your site supports javascript.

Answer (score 2):

How to increase default hover duration of title attribute (tooltip)

Dont use IE, no time limit in Firefox browser. Or use the code I done.

I made some code in html/css only in one file, could not make it easier.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><style>
.m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
.m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #000;background-color:#eee;color:#000;min-width:300px}
</style>
<div class="m"> News         <span> Links inside span works good <a target="_blank" href="http://cnn.com">Cnn.com</a></span></div>
<div class="m"> Hover over here and Information comes up <span> To make complex things easy is not so easy to do. </span></div> 
<br> Just som text here to give you the 3D effect <br>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work well with search engines and screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try WZ tooltip (may no longer be maintained): [Click here](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This is a simple and quick alternative to using jQuery that I may end up using.