# Increasing tooltip showing time in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

All.

Is there some way to increase a tooltip showing time thrown by "title" tag.
Standart time is smaler than 5 seconds or around that, but it's not enough to read the tooltip message.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't. The rendering of these tooltips is done by the browser outside of the scope of the web page and is completely out of your control as a site designer.

The user's browser and/or operating system may provide the ability to modify them, but it would depend on the individual user's setup, so it certainly isn't something you could affect globally so that everyone sees it the same way for your site.

The only way you can make them look different, stay on the screen for longer, or provide any kind of interaction is to write your own replacement tooltip code in Javascript. There are a number of third-party scripts available to do this (turns out a lot of site designers are unsatisfied with the basic `title` tooltip).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you please provide the method of changing  the timeout value for individul user?

Comment: @a.parkhomenko - it's been a very long time since I tried to change that setting. I know it used to be possible in WindowsXP control panel (or possibly Win98? I forget), but I can't find it now in the Windows7 control panel. It's probably there somewhere, but I can't find it. By the way I note that a similar question here on SO a couple of years ago got a very similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530028/how-to-increase-default-hover-duration-of-a-title-attribute-tooltip

Comment: Jep, thanks. You see, using the custom ToolTips realization is Plan B.   Currently, I do expect to find maybe some property in Windows (XP), smth like that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment - but here is what I want to add

You can change the timeout here: "How long should Windows notification dialog boxes stay open"? from 
**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Make it easier to focus on tasks**