# HTML/Javascript - How to increase the time span of a tool tip

Tags: javascript, html

Here the level "This is the description about the image" is display as tool tip when i mouse over on the help icon. but the tool tip is displaying only for 10 secs.

Is there any way to increase the time span of tool tip to 1 mins or till mouse pointer is on the help icon.

Comment: How are you displaying the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the html standard way to have tooltip (ie with the "title" attribute), they are handled by the browser, and its behavior is browser (system ?) - specific.
If you want something that you can handle yourself, I guess you should go for some JS to do it:
For example [here is a demo](http://swip.codylindley.com/tooltipDemo.html%20a%20demo%20of%20tooltip%20in%20js) and [the jquery tooltip plugin wiki page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip%20jquery%20wiki%20page).

The pros of this approach is that you can style your tooltip. The cons is that you have a bit of dev to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are not any conventional ways for that. But you can use some third party js to build custom tooltip. 
Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662359/1805210

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a custom Javascript library for displaying tool tips.

just take a look at [this](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm)

You can also customize the display duration of tooltip using this.