# Text hover box becomes transparent

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been using [code found on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530028/how-to-increase-default-hover-duration-of-a-title-attribute-tooltip) to create a series of text hover boxes which have been working great until I used them for text within a table.  It seems when the hover box pops up over the AREA another box WILL pop up (though not there now), the background becomes transparent, making it very difficult to read the text hover box.

If you look at this code, the upper smiley face in the results has a hover box that you can see the other onscreen text through.  This is my issue.  I played around with the z-index and opacity settings based on some other online searches, but nothing is working so far.

```html
<style>
    .m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
    .m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#ffffff;min-width:300px}
</style>

<div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;"> 
    <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;          
         width: 40px;"/>
    <span><strong><u>second hover box</u></strong>
</div>

<style>
    .m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:5000;position:absolute;display:inline-block}
    .m:hover span{z-index:5001;display:block;position:relative;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#999999;min-width:300px;}
</style>

<div class="m" style="text-align: left;">ON SCREEN TEXT<br/><br/> and some more
    <span> first hover<br/><br/>more hover box</span>
</div>
<br/>
<style>
    .m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
    .m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#ffffff;min-width:300px}
</style>
<div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;"> 
    <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;          
         width: 40px;"/>
    <span><strong><u>second hover box</u></strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. It will help you

```html
<style>
.m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
.m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#000000;min-width:300px;opacity: 0.4; }
</style>
            <div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;"> 
               <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;          
                width: 40px;"/>
                        <span><strong><u>second hover box</u></strong>
            </div>
<style>
.m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:5000;position:absolute;display:inline-block}
.m:hover span{z-index:5001;display:block;position:relative;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#999999;min-width:300px;}
</style>
         <div class="m" style="text-align: left;">ON SCREEN TEXT<br/><br/> and some more
                <span> first hover<br/><br/>more hover box</span></div>
<br/>
<style>
.m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
.m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#ffffff;min-width:300px}
</style>
            <div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;"> 
               <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;          
                width: 40px;"/>
                        <span><strong><u>second hover box</u></strong>
            </div>
```

For more help use this **[link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cd3310/create-an-transparent-color-text-using-html-5/)**

Answer (score 0):

your code is so awfull. LOL

you just need to add z-index on the right place. which is into your div.

your code should be like this:

```
 <style>
    .m span{display: none;list-style: none} .m {z-index:24;position:relative;display:inline-block}
    .m:hover span{z-index:999;display:block;position:absolute;top:19px;left:1em;border:1px solid #0195c8;background-color:#0195c8;color:#ffffff;min-width:300px}
    </style>
    <div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;z-index:25;"> 
        <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;width: 40px;"/>
        <span>
            <strong>
                <u>second hover box</u>
            </strong>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="m" style="text-align: left;">
        ON SCREEN TEXT<br/><br/>and some more
        <span> first hover<br/><br/>more hover box</span>
    </div>
    <br/>


    <div class="m" style="font-family: &#39;trebuchet ms&#39;, helvetica;"> 
        <img src=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QEUhPNc1xag/UHnAq0rQQNI/AAAAAAAAAdI/JgtSqZHDIBY/s1600/smiley%2Bface%2Bwinking.jpg style="margin: 0px;width: 40px;"/>
        <span>
            <strong>
                <u>second hover box</u>
            </strong>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Denny.  I know it is awful, I'm on a real time crunch and had to come up with an example as I couldn't send my real code.  Thank you for your answer, I have a follow-up:  in my real code I have a slew of these that are stacked on top of each other.  As a rule, does the one on time need to have a higher number than the one under?

Comment: I don't know that it did yet as I was hoping you would be able to comment on my follow up question

Comment: does my follow-up question make sense? I've been playing with the z-index numbers and it still seems to be doing it.

Comment: you can use z-index as much as u need. i cant tell you any further if you didnt show your code and what you want.