# increase display time of html title element as tooltip

Tags: tooltip, title

Is there a way to make the tootip that appears from the title element of html items display longer than the roughly 6 seconds it does by default?  Can not use a custom solution involving divs/spans as they do not work in the current framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have the title attribute of an html element to display for a longer time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245936/is-there-a-way-to-have-the-title-attribute-of-an-html-element-to-display-for-a-l)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can, however you might be able to use [nicetitle](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/nicetitle/) instead? it doesnt require you to add divs/spans to your solution.