# How to make the HTML title attribute stay for longer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have a huge html page which is sent as an email. (This is generated by someone else's code and is badly structured) The requirement was to make sure we display some information while scrolling the page. I explored tooltips but was not able to move the tooltip as i was scrolling.

So in order to restore some sanity i divided this huge chunk of data into divs and i am using the HTML title attribute to show this information. Requirement almost satisfied.

However the title attribute provides a tooltip which only stays for some duration. also if the user stops scrolling the page in one of those long divs then it fades away. My question is is there a work around for this?

If anyone knows a better solution please do share (The page will be sent as an email and viewed in outlook so not sure if i can use bootstrap/foundation etc)

Comment: I created a vanilla/native Javascript tooltip, fully customizable in terms of display duration, position and appearance. If you're interested, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the duration of the title tag. Question was asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1245946